# How do I center text inside of a div with Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, centering, text-align

I feel like I'm overthinking this or missing something small. I need to center text inside of a div with Foundation. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
[1]<div class="row">
[2]    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-10 columns">
[3]        My Text for Today
[4]    </div>
[5]</div>
```

I've tried replacing line 1 with the following:

```
<div class="row align-center">
```

I've tried replacing line 2 with the following:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-8 columns centered">
```

I've tried replacing line 5 with the following:

```
<p class="text-centered">My Text for Today</p>
```

I've tried a combination of all three of the above with absolutely no luck.

I'm trying to do this without CSS. Trying to do this with just Foundation. How do I center the `My Text for Today` text?

Comment: Class `align-center` on the `.row` will align columns to the center (while using flexbox). You want to center the text, so `text-align: center`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add the utility class of foundation as

```
<p class="text-center"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

In foundation 6.5 you can align horizontal and vertical with this:

```
<p class="align-center-middle">Text</p>
```